# Ektron: Display page titles instead of website title in tabs

Tags: tabs, title, ektron

I have this request from my client:

> we want page titles to be picked up by the browser and displayed in tabs. We looked in Ektron, but this function doesn't seem to have been activated. Ektron says it does exist, however. Can the master layout be changed to grab page titles?

I've tried to figure out how to do this by going through Ektron's documentation, but the only article I found that was at all close to the issue was this:

[Metadata - How to set Page Title, Keywords & Page Description](http://it.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/ITnvgov/Content/Sections/Application_Development/Web/Procedures/Metadata-PageTitle_Keywords_Description.pdf)

but my pages don't have the Title, Keywords etc fields, they only have MapAddress, Tags, and Image Data. Does anyone know how to make the browser display the page title in the tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom Metadata Definitions inside the Workarea.  Go to Settings > Configuration > Metadata Definitions.  Create a HTML tag called Title.

Once the custom definitions are created, you should then apply them to folders in the Content view.  Go to Content > select a folder > View Properties > Edit > Metadata and then assign your new definition to the folder.  You can choose the root folder if you want the metadata to be available to ALL content.  By default, folders and content inherit settings from their parents.

Once you have that in place, you can add the CMS Metadata control to the page (as per the instructions you are following) and it will pick up the Title.